# Alternatives to FSM in VHDL?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, logic-gates

I want to design a UART using logic gates but I don't know if is there any alternatives to Finite State Machine.

Coding a UART in VHDL using FSM is really easy and abstract, the programmer doesn't know how it is implemented in logic gate level and doesn't know if your design is optimized or not, and doesn't know how many transistor are required for your design.

Comment: a UART is not a stateless logical construct, so it is 'necessarily' and 'inherently' a finite state machine (FSM). If you think of yourself as a 'programmer' when you are authoring VHDL, in my humble opinion, you don't have the right frame of mind going into the exercise. It might look like software, but it's definitively not software, it's a language for synthesizing hardware circuits.

Comment: @vicatcu FSM makes it look like a programming language (sequential) and not like the hardware that it is, I love designing hardware with logic gates and flip flops, but I feel limited, many times I have to resort to FSM and I don't want to do it more

Comment: if you start by 'drawing' the circuit you intend to create, *HDL becomes an exercise in _expressing_ that drawing in the language. Start with an interconnected combinational datapath and identify all your control signals, then design your state machine to orchestrate your control signals and express the resultant logic circuits and wire them to the control signals.

Comment: Nobody designs a module at transistor level in HDL because it's not possible. Let alone at gate level, because it beats the purpose of behavioral modelling and re-usability for which HDLs are used predominantly. You would normally describe your design in HDL in behavioural model and synthesise it to gate-level netlist as devised by the standard cell library.

Comment: Could you post example code of the VHDL that you think "looks like a programming language"?  "Coding a UART in VHDL using FSM is really easy and abstract" sounds like the whole point of VHDL (or any HDL); " the programmer doesn't know ... if your design is optimized or not" well, yes, so?  That's a job for a lower level of design -- after you've bought the best tools and trusted them, of course.  "... and doesn't know how many transistor are required for your design."  So they synthesize it in their chosen technology, and they look at the synthesis report!

Comment: An FSM is not unique to VHDL or Verilig.  An FSM is inherent in the function you're trying to implement, a UART in this case.  I don't care if you use VHDL, a schematic based FPGA tool, or a discrete design using SSI digital parts (gates and flip flops) - in the end you're going to end up with a finite state machine.

Comment: Design it at gate level if you want, it'll still be an FSM. Alternatively, look at the generated RTL from the abstract description (or even the LUT/FF usage report) and compare with your hand-rolled gate level version. I doubt there will be a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

A UART **IS** a FSM, so is a CPU, so is a Counter.... All of the things you do with flipflops and logic and feedback are state machines by definition.

Now you do not necessarily need to implement them in a way that makes that obvious, you could for example do the transmit side of a uart as a 10 bit shift register, with a second one used to signal when the thing finished the byte, not sure it is really a win, but you could design it that way.

You could do it as a counter, then a stack of muxes, still a state machine but you are just hiding it a bit.

I would note that if you think of VHDL as a programming language, and are not writing purely for simulation, you are probably doing it wrong. The trap is that most programmers think in terms of sequential execution most of the time, at best you have a few dozen threads executing. This is not the way to get reasonable performance out of the fabric, where sequence ONLY exists as either a pipeline or because you explicitly wrote a FSM to enforce it.

While a common trap in VHDL is trying to write too close to the metal, a more common trap among programmers encountering a HDL is forgetting that you are describing a circuit not a program.